# vim sort words alphabetically ignore accents

Tags: sorting, vim, accent-insensitive, alphabetized

I want to use vim :sort to alphabetize a list of french words and have sort consider accented words (é) as unaccented (e). French dictionaries are arranged after this fashion. For example, sorting the list "eduquer ébats" yields "ébats eduquer". However, a simple sort with vim yields the first list. Is there a :sort flag i can set to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of `:help :sort`, there's this note:

> The details about sorting depend on the library function used.  **There is no
>   guarantee that sorting obeys the current locale.  You will have to try it out.**
>   Vim does do a "stable" sort.

First, ensure that you're running in a French locale. This can be done inside Vim via

```
:lang fr_FR
```

but it's probably even better to set the `LANG` environment variable in the shell (assuming Linux; on Windows, you probably need to set your user's language accordingly).

If that does not work, you can fall back to an external `sort` (which is commonly provided on Linux, you can also download a Windows port of GNU sort [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)). Sort from Vim via

```
:%! LANG=fr_FR sort ...
```

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 16.04. Neither suggestion worked. :lang fr_FR sorts accented chars to end of sort. GNU sort apparently has no flag to control accented characters. I set LANG variable, again no luck. continuing to search for solution. perhaps will have to use C#???

Comment: Hm, this works for me, in Ubuntu 14.04. `echo -e "ezerel\néfuese\neduquer\nébats" | sort` gives `ébats eduquer éfuese ezerel`; I don't even need to change locale (and use `en_US.UTF-8`). Vim indeed sorts all `e...` before `é...`.

Comment: It isn't clear from your questions... those words are all on separate lines, right? Sort (both Vim and command-line) is line-based.

Comment: Each word is on a separate line. My rough solution is to create a macro that converts accents to unaccented and 'duplicates' the word. For example: "ébats" becomes "ebats:ébats", then run :sort, then strip out "ebats:" do this for all 1200+ word:definition lines. seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sorting with `Unicode::Collate` module from perl.  It's a perl core module.

Assume your word list is written in utf8:

```
:%!perl -CIO -MUnicode::Collate -e '$col = Unicode::Collate->new(level => 1); print for $col->sort(<>)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is no direct vim sort method to accomplish what I want. My workaround consists in setting up 2 macros as mentioned above.

To recap: each line of my text file contains French language "term : definition". Some terms contain accented characters. In order to get the lines alphabetized so that accented letters are treated as unaccented, I wrote a macro the copies the "term", opens a new line, pastes the "term" on that separate line, then invoke a macro that converts accented characters to unaccented in that pasted "term", e.g., let @m=':s/^Vu00e0/a/ge'; my macro is a long string that searches for all accented characters in French.

Once that is done, I cut and paste the modified "term" to the head of the original line and wind up with: "unaccentedterm:accentedterm:definition". Then I run vim :sort, then set up a quick vim macro to strip out the first term, the unaccentedterm.

Many thanks to all who jumped it to help.